# How to clean up this code by using for, forEach or map()?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, foreach, map-function

This is my first question here at stackOverFlow.

https://www.techiesys.in/websites/surya/shop-single.html
Please check the demo here. The codes are working fine, I know I did the worst coding.
I will put the code snippet here.

```js
const changeItem1 = document.getElementById("changeitem1");
const changeItem2 = document.getElementById("changeitem2");
const changeItem3 = document.getElementById("changeitem3");
const changeItem4 = document.getElementById("changeitem4");

function firstChange() {
  changeItem1.classList.remove("d-none");
  changeItem2.classList.add("d-none");
  changeItem3.classList.add("d-none");
  changeItem4.classList.add("d-none");
}

function secondChange() {
  changeItem2.classList.remove("d-none");
  changeItem1.classList.add("d-none");
  changeItem3.classList.add("d-none");
  changeItem4.classList.add("d-none");
}

function thirdChange() {
  changeItem3.classList.remove("d-none");
  changeItem1.classList.add("d-none");
  changeItem2.classList.add("d-none");
  changeItem4.classList.add("d-none");
}

function fourthChange() {
  changeItem4.classList.remove("d-none");
  changeItem1.classList.add("d-none");
  changeItem2.classList.add("d-none");
  changeItem3.classList.add("d-none");
}

const changeFramee1 = document.getElementById("changeframee1");
const changeFramee2 = document.getElementById("changeframee2");
const changeFramee3 = document.getElementById("changeframee3");
const changeFramee4 = document.getElementById("changeframee4");

function f1Change() {
  changeFramee1.classList.remove("d-none");
  changeFramee2.classList.add("d-none");
  changeFramee3.classList.add("d-none");
  changeFramee4.classList.add("d-none");
}

function f2Change() {
  changeFramee2.classList.remove("d-none");
  changeFramee1.classList.add("d-none");
  changeFramee3.classList.add("d-none");
  changeFramee4.classList.add("d-none");
}

function f3Change() {
  changeFramee3.classList.remove("d-none");
  changeFramee1.classList.add("d-none");
  changeFramee2.classList.add("d-none");
  changeFramee4.classList.add("d-none");
}

function f4Change() {
  changeFramee4.classList.remove("d-none");
  changeFramee1.classList.add("d-none");
  changeFramee2.classList.add("d-none");
  changeFramee3.classList.add("d-none");
}
```

```html
<div class="content-side col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="shop-single">

                            <div class="product-details">

                                <!--Basic Details-->
                                <div class="basic-details">
                                    <div class="row clearfix">
                                        <div class="image-column col-md-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 position-relative">

                                            <div id="changeframee1">
                                                <img src="./images/framee.jpeg"
                                                    class="position-absolute framee img-fluid" alt="">
                                            </div>

                                            <div id="changeframee2" class="d-none">
                                                <img src="./images/framee2.jpeg"
                                                    class="position-absolute framee img-fluid" alt="">
                                            </div>

                                            <div id="changeframee3" class="d-none">
                                                <img src="./images/framee3.jpeg"
                                                    class="position-absolute framee img-fluid" alt="">
                                            </div>

                                            <div id="changeframee4" class="d-none">
                                                <img src="./images/framee4.jpeg"
                                                    class="position-absolute framee img-fluid" alt="">
                                            </div>

                                            <figure class="image-box" id="changeitem1"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"
                                                    data-target="#exampleModal" class="lightbox-image"
                                                    title="FRP Doors"><img src="images/00.png" alt=""></a>
                                            </figure>

                                            <figure class="image-box d-none" id="changeitem2"><a href="#"
                                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal2"
                                                    class="lightbox-image" title="FRP Doors"><img src="images/9.png"
                                                        alt=""></a>
                                            </figure>

                                            <figure class="image-box d-none" id="changeitem3"><a href="#"
                                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal3"
                                                    class="lightbox-image" title="FRP Doors"><img src="images/3.png"
                                                        alt=""></a>
                                            </figure>

                                            <figure class="image-box d-none" id="changeitem4"><a href="#"
                                                    data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal4"
                                                    class="lightbox-image" title="FRP Doors"><img src="images/10.png"
                                                        alt=""></a>
                                            </figure>

                                            <div class="changebtns mt-5">
                                                <button onclick="firstChange()"><img src="images/00.png"
                                                        alt=""></button>
                                                <button onclick="secondChange()"><img src="images/9.png"
                                                        alt=""></button>
                                                <button onclick="thirdChange()"><img src="images/3.png" alt=""></button>
                                                <button onclick="fourthChange()"><img src="images/10.png"
                                                        alt=""></button>
                                            </div>

                                        </div>
                                        <div class="info-column col-md-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pl-0 pl-md-5">
                                            <div class="details-header">
                                                <h4>FRP Doors</h4>
                                                <div class="rating">
                                                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                                    <span class="fa fa-star-half-empty"></span>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="item-price">$29.00</div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="text">Not every fiberglass door is equal. Surya’s fiberglass
                                                doors are reliable. Manufactured as part of the industry's only full
                                                door system, they're built and tested to perform better than any other
                                                exterior door and provide style, lasting beauty and durability.</div>

                                            <div class="changeframee mb-4">
                                                <h4>Choose frame</h4>
                                                <button onclick="f1Change()"><img src="images/framee.jpeg"
                                                        alt=""></button>
                                                <button onclick="f2Change()"><img src="images/framee2.jpeg"
                                                        alt=""></button>
                                                <button onclick="f3Change()"><img src="images/framee3.jpeg"
                                                        alt=""></button>
                                                <button onclick="f4Change()"><img src="images/framee4.jpeg"
                                                        alt=""></button>
                                            </div>


                                            <div class="location">Check Delivery Option at Your Location:</div>
                                            <!-- Pincode Form -->
                                            <div class="pincode-form">
                                                <form method="post" action="contact.html">
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <input type="text" name="text" value="" placeholder="Pincode"
                                                            required>
                                                        <button type="submit">Check</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </form>
                                            </div>


                                            <div class="expired">Expected Delivery in 4-10 Days</div>
                                            <div class="other-options clearfix">
                                                <div class="item-quantity"><input class="quantity-spinner" type="text"
                                                        value="2" name="quantity"></div>
                                                <button type="button" class="theme-btn btn-style-two add-to-cart">Add To
                                                    Cart</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--Basic Details-->



                            </div>



                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Please check the snippet and tell me the best solution to avoid this worst coding. 
I have used separate functions for each buttons. I hope there's a way in for, forEach or map loops.
Thank you

Comment: If your code works as is, https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be more helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contains functioning code that only needs optimisation, and is therefore better suited on CodeReview: https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

```js
function change(useChangeItems, removeIndex) {
    items = useChangeItems ? changeItems : changeFramees;
    items.forEach((el, index) => {
        console.log(el);
        if (removeIndex - 1 === index) {
            el.classList.remove("d-none");
        } else {
            el.classList.add("d-none");
        }
    });
}

   
const changeItems = [];
const changeFramees = [];

for (let index = 1; index <= 4; index++) {
let changeItem = document.getElementById(`changeitem${index}`);
changeItems.push(changeItem);
}
for (let index = 1; index <= 4; index++) {
let changeFramee = document.getElementById(`changeframee${index}`);
changeFramees.push(changeFramee);
}
```

```html
 <div class="content-side col-lg-8 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
        <div class="shop-single">

            <div class="product-details">

                <!--Basic Details-->
                <div class="basic-details">
                    <div class="row clearfix">
                        <div class="image-column col-md-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 position-relative">

                            <div id="changeframee1">
                                <img src="./images/framee.jpeg" class="position-absolute framee img-fluid" alt="">
                            </div>

                            <div id="changeframee2" class="d-none">
                                <img src="./images/framee2.jpeg" class="position-absolute framee img-fluid" alt="">
                            </div>

                            <div id="changeframee3" class="d-none">
                                <img src="./images/framee3.jpeg" class="position-absolute framee img-fluid" alt="">
                            </div>

                            <div id="changeframee4" class="d-none">
                                <img src="./images/framee4.jpeg" class="position-absolute framee img-fluid" alt="">
                            </div>

                            <figure class="image-box" id="changeitem1"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#exampleModal" class="lightbox-image" title="FRP Doors"><img
                                        src="images/00.png" alt=""></a>
                            </figure>

                            <figure class="image-box d-none" id="changeitem2"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#exampleModal2" class="lightbox-image" title="FRP Doors"><img
                                        src="images/9.png" alt=""></a>
                            </figure>

                            <figure class="image-box d-none" id="changeitem3"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#exampleModal3" class="lightbox-image" title="FRP Doors"><img
                                        src="images/3.png" alt=""></a>
                            </figure>

                            <figure class="image-box d-none" id="changeitem4"><a href="#" data-toggle="modal"
                                    data-target="#exampleModal4" class="lightbox-image" title="FRP Doors"><img
                                        src="images/10.png" alt=""></a>
                            </figure>

                            <div class="changebtns mt-5">
                                <button onclick="change(true, 1);"><img src="images/00.png" alt=""></button>
                                <button onclick="change(true, 2);"><img src="images/9.png" alt=""></button>
                                <button onclick="change(true, 3);"><img src="images/3.png" alt=""></button>
                                <button onclick="change(true, 4);"><img src="images/10.png" alt=""></button>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                        <div class="info-column col-md-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 pl-0 pl-md-5">
                            <div class="details-header">
                                <h4>FRP Doors</h4>
                                <div class="rating">
                                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
                                    <span class="fa fa-star-half-empty"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="item-price">$29.00</div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="text">Not every fiberglass door is equal. Surya’s fiberglass
                                doors are reliable. Manufactured as part of the industry's only full
                                door system, they're built and tested to perform better than any other
                                exterior door and provide style, lasting beauty and durability.</div>

                            <div class="changeframee mb-4">
                                <h4>Choose frame</h4>
                                <button onclick="change(false, 1);"><img src="images/framee.jpeg" alt=""></button>
                                <button onclick="change(false, 2);"><img src="images/framee2.jpeg" alt=""></button>
                                <button onclick="change(false, 3);"><img src="images/framee3.jpeg" alt=""></button>
                                <button onclick="change(false, 4);"><img src="images/framee4.jpeg" alt=""></button>
                            </div>


                            <div class="location">Check Delivery Option at Your Location:</div>
                            <!-- Pincode Form -->
                            <div class="pincode-form">
                                <form method="post" action="contact.html">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" name="text" value="" placeholder="Pincode" required>
                                        <button type="submit">Check</button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>


                            <div class="expired">Expected Delivery in 4-10 Days</div>
                            <div class="other-options clearfix">
                                <div class="item-quantity"><input class="quantity-spinner" type="text" value="2"
                                        name="quantity"></div>
                                <button type="button" class="theme-btn btn-style-two add-to-cart">Add To
                                    Cart</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Basic Details-->



            </div>



        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please check my other answer in this thread. I have some doubts